# Test if method was called by promise callback

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm developing a test routine that check if some methods are called when a specific method is called.

I'm using jasmine to that.

When I test the first level it's works fine, but if I call another method inside callback function of first level call, jasmine spyOn doesn't works.

A small example if my code:

```
onLogin(form: NgForm) {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (form.valid) {
    this.auth.login(this.login.username, this.login.password).then((value) => {
      if(value) {
        this.menu.enable(true, 'loggedInMenu');
        this.menu.enable(true, 'loggedOutMenu');
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
      } else {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Ops',
          subTitle: 'Some things wrong.',
          buttons: ['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
      }
    });      
  }
}

// Test Routine
describe("onLogin", () => {
    it("makes expected calls when authentication successfully", () => {
        const menuControllerStub = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MenuController);
        const authStub = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Auth);
        const ngFormStub = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NgForm);

        // it isn't works
        spyOn(menuControllerStub, "enable").and.callFake(() => {});

        // it's work fine
        spyOn(authStub, "login").and.callFake((username:string, password: string) => {
            return new Promise((callback, fallback) => {
                callback(true);
            });
        });

        comp.onLogin(ngFormStub);

        // failed
        expect(menuControllerStub.enable).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // success
        expect(autenticacaoStub.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Just for test, I moved two code lines to callback outside and the test works fine. For instance
:

```
onLogin(form: NgForm) {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (form.valid) {
      this.menu.enable(true, 'loggedInMenu');
      this.menu.enable(true, 'loggedOutMenu');

        this.auth.login(this.login.username, this.login.password).then((value) => {
        if(value) {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        } else {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Ops',
            subTitle: 'Some thing wrong.',
            buttons: ['OK']
          });
          alert.present();
        }
    });      
  }
}
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you return a Promise, but it's never resolved or rejected. Try doing

```
    spyOn(authStub, "login").and.callFake((username:string, password: string) => {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    });
```

**EDIT** Please try this :

```
let spy = spyOn(menuControllerStub, 'enable').and.returnValue(false); 
// ...
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

Comment: It's simpler than my code but still does not work. I've put some console.log on login callback and I see that both sample (yours and mine) call this.menu.enable method.

Comment: Ok, and what if you transform your spy with `spyOn(authStub, 'login').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));` ?

Comment: Same behavior. I think the problem is in spyOn(menuControllerStub, "enable") that can't check if the method was called.

Comment: Well you get it from the injector the same way you do for the auth service, and the last one works. From what you posted, the problem for me is that you never actually go into your `then`. Do you have code coverage to back it ? Just look at it and see if your `then` is covered with it

Comment: I've checked if then method was called with a console.log('call enable') into then. It was called.

Comment: Ok my bad then, sorry. Is your menu controller a service like your auth service ? Or is it a component ?

Comment: MenuController is a ionic3 UI control. I've tested you code and apparently the enable method was not called. However I've puted a console.log before calling enable and another one after call. I can see the log messages but the spy does not work. It's so crazy.

Comment: I agree ... Sorry I'm out of ideas here !

Comment: My guess is that jasmine spy can't intercept calls inside callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

Promise is asynchronous, the rest of your test is runned before promise is resolved.

In your case add `tick()` method before  `expect(menuControllerStub.enable).toHaveBeenCalled()`.